# cvAlign Question

Tags: ros, opencv, opencv2.2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short version: Hello, I was wondering what cvAlign does in the inner functions.

Long version:
I've been looking at cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK code and there's a function

```
pyrA = cvGetMat( pyrA, &pstubA );

if( pyrA->step*pyrA->height < icvMinimalPyramidSize( imgSize ) )
    CV_Error( CV_StsBadArg, "pyramid A has insufficient size" );
```

which then leads to this:

```
static int icvMinimalPyramidSize( CvSize imgSize )
{
    return cvAlign(imgSize.width,8) * imgSize.height / 3;
}
```

can anyone tell me what cvAlign does (is it bit alignment)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10450/cvalign-question/) by [Kirielson](https://answers.ros.org/users/750/kirielson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2011-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay I solved my problem.  It seems for Python, at least where I'm running ROS's OpenCV for Python, the images and the pyramids are mixed up if you got the error:  error: pyramid A has insufficient size. So wherever you would put your images, you would then put your pyramids and viceversa.

---

Originally posted by [Kirielson](https://answers.ros.org/users/750/kirielson/) with karma: 20 on 2011-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0